# Modifying one row of an array

Tags: j

I've only just started learning J and there's something I have no idea how to do properly

Suppose i want to print a checkerboard of 2 symbols, for example

```
baba
abab
baba
```

To do this, I assumed you could just generate an array

```
baba
baba
baba
```

and reverse the second line.

Generating the array is easy: `3 4 $ 'ba'`. But reversing the second row is where I struggle.

I can get the reverse of the second row doing `|. 1 { 3 4 $ 'ba'` but that only gives me the second row, not the entire array. I don't see how using J syntax I can actually keep the top and bottom row and only apply `|.` to the middle row.

More generally, how would you apply `|.` only every other row?

Comment: If this question is more about "how should I generate this array" -- you *can* edit arrays (try `'x' 1} 3 4 $ 'ba'`) but there is a more J-like way to do what you want.

Comment: I would write, say, `(2 | (i.3) +/ (i.4)) { 'ba'` for a checkerboard pattern like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What you asked

To apply `|.` to one row, try something like:

```
   x =: 3 4 $ 'ba'
   (|. 1{x) 1} x
baba
abab
baba
```

To reverse every other row, I don't know if there's something simpler than this:

```
   ,/ 1 (]`(|."1))\ i. 5 4
 0  1  2  3
 7  6  5  4
 8  9 10 11
15 14 13 12
16 17 18 19
```

This uses a [relatively obscure feature](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d430.htm) of the dyad `\ (Infix)`:

> `x m\ y` applies successive verbs from the gerund `m` to the infixes of `y`, extending `m` cyclically as required.

Here, `x` is 1, so our "infixes" are just 1×4 matrices; we cycle through a gerund (`` ] ` (|."1) ``) to alternate between doing nothing (`]`) and reversing the single row of the submatrix (`|."1`). Then, we flatten the resulting 5×1×4 array back to a 5×4 matrix with `,/`.

### What you maybe want instead

A much simpler way to achieve a "checkerboard" is as follows: first, use `+/` on two ranges to create an "addition table", like so:

```
   (i.3) +/ (i.4)
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
```

Then take all of these values mod 2, to get a checkerboard pattern of 0s and 1s:

```
   2 | (i.3) +/ (i.4)
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
```

Then index from a string of choice with `{`:

```
   (2 | (i.3) +/ (i.4)) { 'ba'
baba
abab
baba
```

Comment: 8 (2 | +/&i.) 8 or if square,   'ba' ({~ 2 | +/&i.~) 8

Answer (score 4):

#### Way 1: Amending `}`

Replace the second line with the changed line:

```
( 4 $ 'ab') (1 }) m =: 3 4 $ 'ba'
```

or generally, replace with pattern `a =: 4 $ 'ab'`, at indices `i =: +:i.5`:

```
a i } 10 4 $ 'ba'
```

#### Way 2: Cycling with gerund and cut `;.`

You can cyclically apply verbs by tying them with `. For every other row (rank `"1`) you want to either do nothing `]` or reverse `|.`:

```
(]"1)`(|."1) ;.1 m
```

#### Way 3: Using a different pattern

You can see your pattern as `4 $ 'ba'` followed by its inverse:

```
3 $ (,:|.) 4 $ 'ba'
```

#### Incidentally,

having an odd dimension (3) with an even pattern ('ba') allows you the simpler `|: 4 3 $ 'ba'`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you already have a lot of answers, but none of them was the first thing that popped into my head, so I'll add this one:

```
0 1 0 |."(0 1) 3 4$'ba'
```

This takes advantage of the fact that rotating the middle row by 1 looks the same as flipping it.  You can generalize this by computing as long a list of 0 and 1 as you need based on the number of rows in your checkerboard.

Comment: `"0 1` rank is the key here. I, too, was trying to use shift `|.` but missed the dual rank. BTW, shifting is what produces the checkerboard, not flipping; so your solution works for longer patterns whereas most others here fail.

Answer (score 3):

The approach that I would try would not require reversing lines of the array, but works by reframing the situation in a J friendly way.

I would add a column to the array so that I have an odd number columns (5) with an even number of elements ('ba'), then strip off the last item in each row.

```
   4 5$'ba'
babab
ababa
babab
ababa
   }:"1 (4 5$'ba')
baba
abab
baba
abab
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another way of re-framing this specific problem in a "J friendly way", as bob put it.  It doesn't "modify one row" but achieves the desired result in a different way.

```
   |: 4 3 $ 'ba'  NB. transpose a 4x3 matrix
baba
abab
baba
```