# J Checker Board

Tags: functional-programming, j

I need to use J to print a checker board, my function given an odd number needs to create a NxN matrix and place an 'X' in every other box. I have the matrix made but I can not figure out the every other box part.

What I have so far

```
N =: 3 
checker =: (2$N)$ <'X'
```

If anyone could help, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Check out [this almost duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339471/modifying-one-row-of-an-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest route is to use `a:,<'X'` in place of `<'X'`:

```
(2$N)$ a:,<'X'
```

The reason this works is because `x $ y` (*reshape*) reuses `y` cyclically if `*/x` is greater than the number of items in `y`.

Having said that, it might be more interesting to approach this analytically using a fundamental pattern in array programming, which will be much more widely applicable than a fixed number of repetitions or pattern.

Try this:

```
(a:,<'X') {~ 2 | i. ,~ N
```

For example:

```
   (a:,<'X') {~ 2|i.,~5
+-+-+-+-+-+
| |X| |X| |
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X| |X| |X|
+-+-+-+-+-+
| |X| |X| |
+-+-+-+-+-+
|X| |X| |X|
+-+-+-+-+-+
| |X| |X| |
+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Broken down from right-to-left:

1. `y=. ,~ N       NB. Duplicate N; ,~5 becomes 5,5`
2. `y=. i.y       NB. NxN table of the first N^2 non-negative integers`
3. `y=.2|y        NB. y mod 2, so an NxN table of 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...`
4. `y=.(a:,<'X') {~ y       NB. Map 0 to ace (empty) and 1 to <'X'`

Packed up as a re-usable verb:

1. Explicit: `cb =: verb def ' (a:,<'X') {~ 2 | i. ,~ y'`
2. Tacit: `cb =:  (a:,<'X') {~ 2 | i.@,~`

This pattern of creating an  array of all possible results, and indexing all outputs into them simultaneously, is one of the fundamental mechanics of array programming, and widely used in a number of different idioms.

Comment: while this works it is much more advanced than anything we have learned in class!

Comment: @MichaelMiner Initially I overthought it (or over generalized it); I added a simpler and much more direct method to the top of my answer. This is more likely to be what your teacher is looking for.

Comment: @MichaelMiner Sure: `a: , <'X'`  is a list of two boxes: the second box is your original `<'X'` and the first is the empty box, also known as `a:` (*ace*). So now you have (empty-box)(box-with-X), and `(2$N) $ ...` makes a checkerboard pattern by repeating that over and over again.

Comment: makes sense! Thanks for your quick replies to this, no one seems to even know what J is!

Comment: @MichaelMiner True, but those of us who do really love it.

Comment: I am learning to like it but find the lack of resources very frustrating

Comment: @DanBron, you left out the caveat that your solution only works with odd-sized boards. If you try to generate the real 8x8 checkerboard with your code, the result is columns. I'm trying to think of a better solutions than `}: }:"1 cb 9`

Comment: @Dane Thanks, I should have made that caveat explicit for my first answer (though the constraint to odd integers is expressed in the original question). I'll think about a better generalized solution. FYI, `_1 _1 }. y` is the same as `}: }:"1 y`, but a little briefer.